# Transaction using SwapExactEthforTokens is being sandwiched by bots

Tags: pancakeswap, swaps

I am using a smart contract to buy scam free token.But buy transaction is being sandwiched by some bot.
In our swapexactethfortokens we are providing calculated AmountOutMin value so i think slippage is not an issue.

What could be the exact reason?

Answer (score 0):

The exact reason for your buy transaction being sandwiched by a bot is likely due to the fact that the bot is trying to capitalize on an arbitrage opportunity. By buying up tokens before your transaction is complete, the bot is able to purchase them at a lower price and then sell them off at a higher price once your transaction is complete. This is a common practice among traders and is known as arbitrage trading. The best way to protect yourself from this type of activity is to ensure that you are buying your tokens at the lowest possible price. This can be done by ensuring that you use the AmountOutMin value that is provided by the smart contract. By doing this, you should be able to minimize the slippage that is caused by the bot.

Comment: But when my Slippage is minimum even then the other bot is attacking
Check these transaction so that you get exact insight to whats happening
Our trade https://bscscan.com/tx/0x8026a80c973040076d1fec4f8e53c3b6d2bab0bfa875b0fd97ef0ed30e2bbad1
Bot trade - https://bscscan.com/tx/0xd2867ff85b5fbf2905a754dbb805aefef9909a8819625cf99a9263e928d19b7f

Comment: There is no definitive answer as it depends on the type of bot you are dealing with and the strategies it is using. However, some strategies bots use to attack other bots include exploiting their weaknesses, trying to outmaneuver them, using a variety of different tactics, and exploiting any gaps in their defenses or strategies.